# Error while updating the Entity using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0

I have an student object which has many to one relationship with the department object. I have inserted the student object into the database without the Department object.

I am trying to update the Student object by loading the Department objects into a combo box. I am doing this when user click on a row in the datagridview. Here is my code.

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        long studentid = (long)dr.Cells[0].Value;

        using(var ctx=new DatabaseFirstEntities())
        {
            var st = ctx.Students.Find(studentid);
            if(st!=null)
            {
                utextstydentname.Text = st.Name;
                upstlastname.Text = st.LastName;
                dateTimePicker3.Value = st.DOB;

                var deparments=ctx.Departments.ToList();



                comboBox1.DataSource = deparments;
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DepartmentName";
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "DepartmentName";

                updatestudent = st;
            }
        }
    }

      private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(var ctx=new DatabaseFirstEntities())
        {
            Department d = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Department;

            long did = d.DepartmentId;

            updatestudent.Department = d;
            ctx.Entry(updatestudent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

But when i hit the update button i get the below error.
{"A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Department.DepartmentId' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Student.DepartmentId' on the other end."}

Please help.

```
  public partial class Student
{
    public long StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}



public partial class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        this.Teachers = new HashSet<Teacher>();
    }

    public long DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}
```

}

[image]

Your suggestion did work. But is that the right way ?

Because i can create the entity like this.

```
     Department d = new Department { DepartmentName = "Psychology" };
        Student st=new Student(){ Name="Student4",LastName="",DOB=DateTime.Now,Department=d};

        var ctx = new DatabaseFirstEntities();
        ctx.Students.Add(st);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

So why cant I use the navigation property if i want to update?

Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Can you post your Student and Department entities?

Comment: I have added the entites

Comment: Can you debug 'DepartmentId' This must be in Department table.

Comment: Instead of updateStudent.Department = d , try updateStudent.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId... basically update the foreign key value rather than the navigation property

Comment: Thanks. It did work. But is that the right way? because i can create something like this.

Comment: Probably when you only assign the `Department` property the `Student.DepartmentId` still refers to a different department. So you must either assign the the foreign key and set the navigation property to null, or else assign the navigation property and set the foreign key to null.

Comment: I can assign the foreign key and set the navigation property to null. This works but the vice versa still errors out.